# url re write issue in .htaccess file

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Here is my problem

in my website base url am redirecting to an inside folder

```
eg: http://example.com/ 

     to 

http://onlinevyapari.com/business/ by using this code in .htaccess file 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /business/index.php [L]
```

now I want to use search engine friendly url for the same website my query is like this 
    http://example.com/business-details.php?id=106

but I want to keep my url like this
    http://example.com/business-details/106

I have done in different way like bellow

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule business-details/id/(.*)/ business-details.php?id=$1
RewriteRule business-details/id/(.*) business-details.php?id=$1
```

its happening but css is not loading properly

it will be really appreciable to me if somebody help.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ business/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^business-details/(\d+)/?$ business-details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

For solving css/js/image path issues just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Alternatively** you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable help. 
its working and page is loading but css is not loading :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following, before your rules, to make the rewrite rules ignore file and directory names.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: thanks for your help but its not working
its throwing PDO Error